# Startup class in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: owin

I am curious about Startup class in ASP.NET MVC 5, when I remove the assembly attribute from the Startup class, the code inside Startup class is still being executed.

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using SignalRChat;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

//[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRChat.Startup))]
namespace SignalRChat
{
   public class Startup
   {
       public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
       {
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
   }
}
```

Anybody can tell me why this happened?

Thanks

Comment: try to clean the build and rebuild the solution

Answer (score 8):

[OWIN Startup Class Detection | The ASP.NET Site](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection):

> You connect the startup class with the hosting runtime using one of the these approaches:
>
> - **Naming Convention**: Katana looks for a class named Startup in namespace matching the assembly name or the global namespace.
> - `OwinStartup` Attribute: This is the approach most developers will take to specify the startup class.
> - The appSetting element in the Configuration file

Emphasis mine. Your class is used because of its name.